# Copy the file created newly in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory where so many files created daily and need to copy the new files which were generated. And all files will be created with starting name abc_

Ex:I have a file abc_0520123.pdf on the next day two files were created abc_0521234.pdf and abc_0521254.pdf now I want to copy only these two files created newly.

Please help me how can I compare old files with new one and to copy them.

Comment: all files will be created with starting name "abc_monthdaterandomnumb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find.

```
find /my_directory -mtime -1d   # Finds everything modified less than one day ago.
find /my_directory -ctime -1d   # Finds everything created less than one day ago.
find /my_directory -ctime +5d   # Finds stuff created more than 5 days ago.
```

If you want to move the files you can use `-exec`

```
find /my_directory -mtime -1d -type f -exec mv {} /new_dir/. \;
```

Finds files only located under /my_directory which are less than 1 day old and moves them to /new_dir

Find is one of the most useful commands you can ever learn!

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Here I need to run this for automation process. So I am going to write this in script, but here I have a problem that files are generated only when the input source file is submitted. These source files will be submitted only on workdays. 
Ex: If input file submitted on Friday and the main file will be generated on Saturday.So if the generated file already copied to another directory it should not be copied again. So how can I check the old file with the new one. There are chances that input file may not be submitted and in that case no files were generated